# App starts with black screen in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I changed "Launch Screen File" to my "Main.Storyboard" in settings. Before doing this app was working fine, and opened directly without any problem. But after adding this there was a black screen before the launch of storyboard. This is very bad user experience. Help me to solve this. AppDelegate and viewController has nothing big. I have a LaunchScreen.xib in project and also LaunchImage in image assets. I am using Storyboard in project. I don't want a launchScreen in my app, I just wanna directly go to my storyboard.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = utilitiesObjet.getViewController("MainVC", mainStoryBoardName: "Main")
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self()])

        return true
    }
```

[image]

I solved it by adding a LaunchScreen.StoryBoard, Instead of using a LaunchScreen.xib. Thank you All :)

Comment: what r you use....xib  ya storyboard in project... ?

Comment: I am using Storyboard

Comment: This may be because there is an outlet on your storyboard's initial view cotroller, which will cause nothing to render. Nothing will also happen if your initial view controller is a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code in appdelegate this code for objective c
.....did finish launching with option method...

```
        self.winow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"<Your Storyboard name>" bundle:nil];
        LoginViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<your view controller storyboard identifer name>"];
        UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ivc];

        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

For Swift....

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navigationController:UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as UINavigationController
    let rootViewController:UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC") as UIViewController
    navigationController.viewControllers = [rootViewController]
    self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    return true
}
```

Comment: in objective c it's working....but i don't know...about swift..so find swift code...

Comment: tell me what is the issue?

Comment: Hey i found the code, Just like you said. Still there is that black.

Comment: can you add this line...self.winow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

Comment: give me your view controller name

Comment: I just modified the question, please take a look.

Comment: remove main from launch screen file

Comment: Give me a sec please.

Comment: I didnt understand, why you are using UINavigationController.

Comment: i need navigation controller in my app so i added navigation contoller ...if you don't need then remove navigation line....

Comment: Yes sure :) Also Add this line in your answer " adding a LaunchScreen.StoryBoard, Instead of using a LaunchScreen.xib."

Answer (score 0):

Launch Screen different Main.StoryBoard. In Launch Screen File, you must type: "LaunchScreen" and choose file Lscreen.storyboard (xcode7), or .xib if Xcode6